# Initialize either empty pile of cards or a full deck with a bool in C#

Tags: c#, object, enums

Ok, I have to write a solitaire game and the first thing I have to do is create a card class and a pile class.

Card class initializes either a blank card or a defined card...

```
public enum Suit { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades }

public enum FaceValue {
    Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine,
    Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace
}

public enum Color {
    Red, Black
}



public class Card{
    private FaceValue faceValue;
    private Suit suit;
    private Color color;


    //construct a blank card
    public Card() { }


    // constuct a defined card
    public Card(FaceValue FV, Suit S, Color C) {
        faceValue = FV;
        suit = S;
        color = C;
    }
```

And then, here is my CardPile Class

```
    //create a empty CardPile
    public CardPile() { }

    public List<Card> pile;
    public CardPile(bool newdeckquestionmark) {
        pile = new List<Card>();
        if (newdeckquestionmark) {
            int index = 0;
            int c;
            foreach (Suit s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit))) {
                foreach (FaceValue fv in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FaceValue))) {
                    if ((index < 13) || (index > 38)) {
                        c = (int)Color.Red;
                    } else {
                        c = (int)Color.Black;
                    }

                    pile.Add(new Card()); // works
                    // pile.Add(new Card (fv, s, c)); // - FAILS.
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I don't know where I've gone wrong, whether it's in the card properties or in how I'm writing pile.Add but I want that FOREACH FaceValue, FOREACH Suit loop to insert the 52 cards....

when I put in

```
pile.Add(new Card (fv, s, c));
```

I get the error,

> The best overloaded method match for 'Shared_Game_Class_Library.Card.Card(Shared_Game_Class_Library.FaceValue, Shared_Game_Class_Library.Suit, Shared_Game_Class_Library.Color)' has some invalid arguments...

Answer (score 3):

`c` is an `int`, and the constructor is expecting a `Color`:

```
public Card(FaceValue FV, Suit S, Color C)
```

You could cast your `c` to `Color`, but you should just change the declared type of `c` to `Color`. There's no reason I can see to use `int`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that when I set something to equal an enum, it was really just setting it as the index of that particular enum...

Answer (score 0):

I guess because your c is int not Color
Try to convert it to your Color. If it is enum then why you convert it to int? Change you int c; into Color c;